# PA of Big O notation

Tags: big-o

considering the following loop:

```
while(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  System.out.println();
}
```

Is it big `o(n)` or `o(1)` ?? 
What makes me think that it is 
`o(1)` is in the boolean expression 
we wrote `i <= 10` and not `i <= n`
Or should I not care for this 
detail ?

Comment: `O(1)`, because number of operations performed is **constant**

Comment: Well, the code doesn't have `n` at all, that's why it has `O(1)` time complexity (i.e. constant execution time). I would be `O(n)` for, say, `while(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {System.out.println();}`

Answer (score 0):

When we say a simple for loop has a time complexity of O(N), we mean that the time it takes to execute the loop depends on the input size of N. For instance

```
function doLoop(n) {
     let i = 0;
     while (i < n) {
         console.log('doing stuff');
         i++;
     }
```

In that function, if we pass 2, our loop executes twice and if we pass 100 it'll run 100 times, etc.

In your loop- we're not passing any input at all. The loop will ALWAYS execute exactly 10 times. So its O(10). Typically, when expressing Big O notation, we ignore constant values, and since O(10) => 10 * O(1); your for loop is O(1), a constant time loop that does not depend on the size of any input variables.